# How to convert my spacy program to executable file

Tags: pyinstaller, spacy

I Have a python script for named entity recognition which uses spacy and few other external packages.how can i convert this python script to a executable file

Comment: [Here is the pyinstaller manual](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/). You should start there and come back if you have a question about a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently started trying out the pex format: https://pex.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

This is really just like a .jar file You still need Python on the host system, but it packs up all the wheels, files etc into a zip, which it then runs for you. I think is the right compromise --- if you try to get the interpreter in the file as well, you may as well have a container.

I haven't tested this with models yet, but I've been building .pex files for spaCy, and have added a pex command to the build system. So now if you have fabric or fabric3 you can do:

```
git clone https://github.com/explosion/spaCy
fab env make wheel pex
```

This makes a virtualenv, uses it to compile spaCy from source, builds a wheel, and then packs that wheel and the dependencies into a .pex file, that runs the "spacy" command.

For your purpose, you would want to point pex at a model package, and write yourself a run script which worked the way you want.